# How to scale a Highchart chart ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to develop a timeline feature for a website, and I'm using the multichart API from Highcharts. However, as the data points grows fast, it gets crowded fast and the chart doesn't scale properly, like using a timeline. 
Here is a sample from Highcharts:

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            }],
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +'°C';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true

            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mm';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                }

            }, { // Tertiary yAxis
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +' mb';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#AA4643'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                x: 120,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 80,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Rainfall',
                color: '#4572A7',
                type: 'column',
                yAxis: 1,
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' mm'
                }

            }, {
                name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                type: 'spline',
                color: '#AA4643',
                yAxis: 2,
                data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dashStyle: 'shortdot',
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' mb'
                }

            }, {
                name: 'Temperature',
                color: '#89A54E',
                type: 'spline',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' °C'
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes/) chart is similar with the one I'm working on. And I wanted something similar with [This](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/) sample: with the possibility of choosing a range from a time period ... How can I accomplish that?

Comment: did you check this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

Comment: If you have license for Highstock, then use second example and add more series. Adding more series is exactly the same as in first example.